# Angular Forms : [selected] not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Here's is my TS code :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  datas = [{id:1, lib: "London"}, {id:2, lib: "Madrid"}, {id: 3, lib: "Berlin"}]

  myCity = "London";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      city: new FormControl()
    })
  }

}
```

And here is my template :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="go()">
  <select name="" formControlName="city">
    <option *ngFor="let data of datas" [value]="data.id" [selected]="myCity == data.lib">{{data.lib}}</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit()">click</button>
</form>
```

I can see my form working properly with my 3 values I can choose. But by default I should see "London" but nothing appear. By default my value is null.

I don't undersand why. My code seems correct

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove completely that `selected` attribute and modify code where form is created:

```
city: new FormControl('1') // London has id 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it can work that way. But in my real project both my form structure, data etc... come from REST API so I dynamically create formGroup with plenty of data comling from HTTP protocol. I can't go into details but trust me, it's pretty hard. I would like to initialize data directly in my template. Is this possible without initalizing FormControl ?

Comment: To be honest I would need at least small part of code but I belive even if you create it dynamically you can still somehow set default value

Comment: Yeah it is possible and probably will do. but I wish I could juste use [selected], seems much easier

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `formControlName="city"` and your code will work like charm. Reason is you are binding two times one is with `formControlName="city"` and another one is with the `selected` property.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="go()">
  <select name="">
    <option *ngFor="let data of datas" [value]="data.id" [selected]="myCity == data.lib">{{data.lib}}</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit()">click</button>
</form>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmcbh7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: You still show `formControlName="city"` in your code?

Comment: @AmitChigadani Opps forgot to remove while pasting as answer. Answer Updated

Comment: But if I remove formControlName, this select control is no longer part of my formGroup instance

Comment: yes, right. so you should need only binding either it's `selected` or `formControlName`. I posted solution with `selected` one as you ask in the question

Comment: I am not sure you are correct about removing the FormControlName from the select element. This caused an issue for me in 2021 but this might be due to newer angular versions.

Comment: @d0rf47 so what makes your code correct if you have not removed `FormControlName`?

Comment: @PardeepJain the combination of the two worked for me.